# Guided-LDA without collapsed gibbs sampling

Tags: python, machine-learning, sampling, markov-chains, mcmc

I'm using the python package Guided-LDA with collapsed gibbs sampling [[more details](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/guidedlda/)]. But I want guided-LDA without collapsed gibbs sampling.

How can I separate guided-LDA and collapsed gibbs sampling or how can I get results without collapsed gibbs sampling?

```
model = guidedlda.GuidedLDA(n_topics=5, n_iter=100, random_state=7, refresh=20)
model.fit(X, seed_topics=seed_topics, seed_confidence=0.15)
```

Comment: To clarify, you don't want Gibbs sampling at all or you want Gibbs sampling but not the collapsed version?

Comment: i don't want Gibbs sampling at all

Comment: if we train model with n_iter=0..... is it mean that collapsed gibbs sampling is not executing?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to MCMC is variational inference (which is used in vanilla LDA). I do not know if somebody implemented VI for guided LDA, worst case you have to do it yourself.

Luckily nowadays it is quite easy e.g. through pyro for pytorch ([tutorial](http://pyro.ai/examples/svi_part_i.html)) or tensorflow probability ([tutorial](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/03/variational-autoencoders-with.html)).